# CS0118: 'System.Security.Cryptography.PBKDF2' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Tags: visual-studio, hash, cryptography, visual-studio-2015, pbkdf2

I installed the PBKDF2 package from Nuget, for Visual Studio 2015.

And I was using [This resource](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#aspsourcecode) to hash my password field.

```
public static string CreateHash(string password)
{
    // Generate a random salt
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider csprng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_BYTE_SIZE];
    csprng.GetBytes(salt);

    // Hash the password and encode the parameters
    byte[] hash = PBKDF2(password, salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, HASH_BYTE_SIZE);
    return PBKDF2_ITERATIONS + ":" +
        Convert.ToBase64String(salt) + ":" +
        Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

But I get this:

Compiler Error Message: CS0118: 'System.Security.Cryptography.PBKDF2' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

This is for the PBKDF2 call in the line -> byte[] hash = PBKDF2(password, salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, HASH_BYTE_SIZE);

So how do I apply that as a variable instead of method and still pass those arguments?

Also why do i get that error in the first place?
That [source](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#aspsourcecode) looks like a really good source and is referenced in quite a few places including questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I went through a lot of websites, and examples and it seems that this method will work

```
        using (var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS))
    {
        hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(24);
    }
```